# Bluetooth debugging tools

Tags: bluetooth

Linux has hcidump which is a very handy tool for debugging bluetooth problems.

Can anyone recommend similar tools for Windows? I'd also be interested in other tools for Linux if anyone knows anything good.

I'm trying to investigate why my BT device disconnects after a couple of seconds. I expect its a crappy mini-dongle, but would like to find out more about where the disconnection originated from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you have something similar for Windows desktop, but for Windows CE there is a tool called [BTDC Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328900). If you read Wireshark wiki they say that there isn't something for Windows: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth and http://wiki.wireshark.org/Bluetooth

You could capture the traffic, by going deep into the driver, but for this you should study the Windows DDK. It allows you to add extensions of your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the USB interface with a Windows USB sniffer, e.g. Usbtrace or Usblyzer and convert the captured output to btsnoop file format which can then be loaded and analyzed in Wireshark or FTS4BT viewer (free tool from ww.fte.com).