# Bluetooth Debugging on windows. ULZ file to btsnoopfile

Tags: bluetooth

Looking at this article:

[Bluetooth debugging tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306982/bluetooth-debugging-tools)

You can capture Bluetooth traffic by capturing the USB port data. This I have done and saved the file as a .ULZ file. The problem is that the article doesn't tell you haw to do the conversion of the file into a btsnoop file.

Does anybody have any ideas?